# su to LDAP user in bash script

Tags: bash, ldap

We have a partial LDAP integration on our RHEL servers.  I'm trying to create a setup script to run on new servers.  The first thing I need my script to do is log into an LDAP user account so that it's home directory gets created.  If I put it in a script like so (and run as root):

```
#!/bin/bash
su - LDAPaccount
```

It fails saying the user doesn't exist.
If I just run the su - LDAPacccount command, then it creates the users home directory and switches me to that user.  Anyone know why running the su command in a bash script fails and how I can get around this?

Comment: Which editor do you use for creating the script file?

Comment: Can you post explicitly how you execute the script and its exact output when it fails?

Comment: I'm using VI as my editor.  To run it, i run ./scriptname


it then says "user LDAPaccount does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this.  My solution was to fully qualify everything:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/su - LDAPaccount -c "/usr/bin/ls"
```

When I run that, it works fine.